# How to 'decode' array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `.ini` file. This is what an `.ini` file looks like:

```
[something]
a = b
c = d
e = f
g = h
```

I have the following PHP code:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file("data.ini", true);
print_r($ini);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [something] => Array
        (
            [a] => b
            [c] => d
            [e] => f
            [g] => h
        )

)
```

Is there a way to 'decode' the array? For example, that the output is this:

```
a => b
c => d
e => f
g => h
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$ini['something']`? Looks like `parse_ini_file` also gives you the sections.

Comment: @bali182 `Notice: Undefined index: something`

Comment: The array is "decoded" from the INI file and should be used as-is, as a Map (perhaps with iteration of the key/value pairs). `$ini["a"] // => "b"`. See a tutorial/reference, eg. http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html , http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Decode what has just been decoded, thats an interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this :

```
$ini = parse_ini_file("data.ini", true);


foreach ($ini['something'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " => ". $value."<br />";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a => b
c => d
e => f
g => h
```

Comment: That works, but I still see `Array ( [something] => Array ( [a] => b [c] => d [e] => f [g] => h ) )`. After that I just see `a => b` etc.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards, I can't help but I feel that you simply copy/pasted the code above without actually **understanding** it. Try to figure out what's going on first and then you can actually get the desired output.

Comment: @WilliamDavideEdwards Because `$ini` is an array containing other arrays. Try `print_r($ini['something'])` you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Its same as mentioned in php page

```
<?php
$fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');

reset($fruit);
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruit)) {
    echo "$key => $val\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works with `.ini` files.

Comment: `reset()`, `list()` and `each()`. R.I.P. `foreach`.